# Android Absolute Layout with different screen size

Tags: android, absolutelayout

I'm using Absolute Layout to divide the screen to 4 species with circle in the center like this
[image]

It is work fine with small screen size but with large screen it doesn't.
How to do this with different screen width?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:l="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#fcf2cf"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.organizer2.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:background="#219baa"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="148dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:background="#ef820b"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="180dp"
        android:background="#e3c800"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="148dp"
        android:layout_y="180dp"
        android:background="#36bc89"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:layout_y="132dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

   </AbsoluteLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: AbsoluteLayout was deprecated on API level 3 and should not be used. 
You can use a FrameLayout and use gravity to set button and circle positions. Also you will need to make a custom view for Button to make them square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbsolueLayouts are a big no-no since they don't do anything with devices of different sizes. Try and achieve this view with using a combination of [LinearLayouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html). By setting all the buttons to be inside of linearlayout and giving each button a weight of 1, we are telling them all to grow, which would not happen inside of an absolute layout. The linearlayouts themselves are also in a linearlayout and also have been given weights so they will grow as there is extra screen space to occupy (nested LinearLayouts are not great for performance but don't worry about that as of now, since you still seem to be learning the basics and users of your app will not notice any delay). :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#fcf2cf"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:id="@+id/linear"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight=1
           android:orientation="hoizontal" >

                 <Button
                 android:id="@+id/Button1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#219baa"
                 android:text="Button" />

                 <Button
                 android:id="@+id/Button2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#ef820b"
                 android:text="Button" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:id="@+id/linear"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight=1
           android:orientation="hoizontal" >

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#e3c800"
                android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#36bc89"
                android:text="Button" />

          </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

   </AbsoluteLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, i'm using linearlayout but i canot put the circle in the center like my image

Comment: sorry I updated my answer to include in circle image android:layout_centerVertical="true"